# Why does Flask return <embed> files to download instead of displaying them

Tags: python, html, svg, flask, jinja2

When I render a template using Flask which contains  images, the files are returned for download instead of being displayed.

More specifically,

```
<embed src="static/yes.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
```

If I put this inside test.html and open it in Google Chrome, the image file will be displayed.

If I use exactly the same in a Flask template and use

```
render_template("test.html")
```

Then Chrome downloads the image file.

Is this expected behaviour from the Jinga2 Templates system that Flask uses? And if so, is there a work-around (other than converting the .svg files to .png or .jpg) to make them display instead?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with embedding SVG in HTML, but I feel that this is probably more of a browser issue than a flask issue. Have you tried the other methods listed here: http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp

Answer (score 0):

Using an `<img>` tag works perfectly on my Flask application in both Chrome and Firefox